# sort data in hdb by using dbmain.q in kdb

Tags: kdb

I am trying to sort 1 or 2 columns in a hdb in kdb but failed. This is the code I have

```
fncol[dbdir;`trade;`sym;xasc];
```

and got a length error when I called it. But I don't have a length error if I use this code

```
fncol[dbdir;`trade;`sym;asc];.
```

However this only sorts the `sym` column itself. I want the data from other columns change according to `sym` column as well.

In addition, I would like to apply parted attribute to sym column. Also, I tried to sort this way

```
fncol[dbdir;`trade;`sym`ptime;xasc];. also failed
```

Comment: can you hold the entire table for 1 date in memory?

Comment: not too sure. but it has many dates

Comment: did selecting from your table work prior till you playing with dbmaint? I think one of those func calls has messed it up

Comment: yeah. its working

Comment: so its still working if you select from it after dbmaint?

Comment: right now i just load into memory and sort and save and then use dbmaint to setattrcol. but got 'u fail when setting up the `p attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always be careful with dbmaint.q if you are unsure what it is going to do. I gather from the fact `asc` worked after `xasc` that you are using a test hdb each time.

`fncol` should be used with unary functions i.e. 1 argument. It's use case is for modifying individual columns. What you are trying to do is modifying the entire table as you want to sort the entire table relative to the sym column. Using .Q.dpft for each date is what you want as outlined by Cathal in your follow-up question. [using .Q.dpft function to resave table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044905/using-q-dpft-function-to-resave-table)

When you run this `` fncol[dbdir;`trade;`sym;xasc]; `` You are saving down a projection in place of the sym column in each date.

```
fncol[`:.;`trades;`sym;xasc];
select from trades where date = 2014.04.21
'length
  [0]  select from trades where date = 2014.04.21

q)get `:2014.04.21/trades/sym
k){$[$[#x;~`s=-2!(0!.Q.v y)x;0];.Q.ft[@[;*x;`s#]].Q.ord[<:;x]y;y]}[`p#`sym$`A..
// This is the k definition of xasc with the sym column as the first parameter.

q)xasc
k){$[$[#x;~`s=-2!(0!.Q.v y)x;0];.Q.ft[@[;*x;`s#]].Q.ord[<:;x]y;y]}

// Had you needed to fix your hdb, I managed to undo this using value and indexing to the sym col data.

fncol[`:.;`trades;`sym;{(value x)[1]}];

q)select from trades where date = 2014.04.21
date       sym  time                          src price size
------------------------------------------------------------
2014.04.21 AAPL 2014.04.21D08:00:12.155000000 N   25.31 2450
2014.04.21 AAPL 2014.04.21D08:00:42.186000000 N   25.32 289
2014.04.21 AAPL 2014.04.21D08:00:51.764000000 O   25.34 3167
```

asc will not break the hdb as it just takes 1 argument and saves down ONLY the sym column in ascending order not the table.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any indication of what date is failing with a length error? It could be something wrong with one of the partitions.

Perhaps if you try to load one of the dates into memory and sort it manually IE

```
`sym xasc select from trade where date=last date
```

that might indicate if there's a specific partition causing issues.

FYI if you're intersted in applying the `p#` attribute you should try `setattrcol` in dbmaint.q. I think the data will need to be sorted first though.

Comment: yes but i got `s eorr or something. i think i need to sort first

Comment: i got the length error only when i call the table. not when sorting.

Comment: You're getting a length error when you try to load the database? Or when you try to select from it?

Comment: when calling the table. loading is fine

Comment: Can you check if the size of the sym file within one of the partition directories is the same size as another integer column? They should be the same.

Comment: ok  i think i'll load and resave. do you know why i got `u error when i apply parted attribute to hdb sym column? i used dbmaint setattricol function

Comment: The sym column needs to be sorted first Terry before the attribute can be applied, that's why you were seeing the `'u-fail` error. Are you able to sort the data before saving it down?