# using .Q.dpft function to resave table

Tags: kdb

I am trying to load the data for each date and then sort the `sym` column and apply the parted attribute. But I don’t know how to use the `.Q.dpft` function to save to the same table?

There is a trade table in hdb.
Here is my function:

```
\l dbdir;
test:{
    trade:select from trade where date = x;
    trade:`sym xasc trade;
    .Q.dpft[dbdir;x;`sym;`trade]}each date;
```

Doesn’t seem to be working though. The error is ``trade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass the table `trade` & `dbdir` as arguments to your function since you're referencing them inside the function.

```
test:{[dbdir;table;x]
  trade:select from table where date = x;
  .Q.dpft[dbdir;x;`sym;table]}[dbdir;`trade]each date
```

Also perhaps worth noting that `.Q.dpft` will take care of sorting the `sym` column for you, so no need to sort it separately.